# WP8.1 не работает кодировка windows-1251

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Необходимо из массива байт перевести текст в кодировке windows-1251 в строку.
Для этого я использую встроенное средство:

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
```

Однако этот код выдаёт исключение:

```
'windows-1251' is not a supported encoding name.
Parameter name: name
```

Никак не могу понять, что здесь не так, в интернете и даже на англоязычном stackoverflow именно так вопрос с кодировкой и решают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью сторонней библиотеки https://github.com/jstedfast/Portable.Text.Encoding легко получилось декодировать из кодировки windows-1251. Пример кода:

```
var bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
Encoding encoding = Portable.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
var text = encoding.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему  `System.Text.Encoding` поддерживает всего три кодировки:

```
System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode
System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
```

Соответственно он не может найти windows-1251. Ибо такой кодировки он не знает.

Чтобы использовать windows-1251 кодировку вам нужно реализовать свой класс, наследующийся от `System.Text.Encoding` и описывающий данную кодировку.

Примерно так:

```
public class Windows1251 : Encoding 
{
    static string alpha = "\0\a\b\t\n\v\f\r !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ЂЃ‚ѓ„…†‡€‰Љ‹ЊЌЋЏђ‘’“”•–—™љ›њќћџ ЎўЈ¤Ґ¦§Ё©Є«¬­®Ї°±Ііґµ¶·ё№є»јЅѕїАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
    public override int GetByteCount(char[] chars, int index, int count)
    {
        return count;
    }

    public override int GetBytes(char[] chars, int charIndex, int charCount, byte[] bytes, int byteIndex)
    {
        byte questionIndex = (byte)alpha.IndexOf('?');
        for (int i = 0; i < charCount; i++)
        {
            int toIndex = byteIndex + i;
            int index = alpha.IndexOf(chars[charIndex + i]);
            if (index == -1)
                bytes[toIndex] = questionIndex;
            else
                bytes[toIndex] = (byte)index;
        }
        return charCount;
    }

    public override int GetCharCount(byte[] bytes, int index, int count)
    {
        return count;
    }

    public override int GetChars(byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, int byteCount, char[] chars, int charIndex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; i++)
        {
            chars[i + charIndex] = alpha[bytes[byteIndex + i]];
        }
        return byteCount;
    }

    public override int GetMaxByteCount(int charCount)
    {
        return charCount;
    }

    public override int GetMaxCharCount(int byteCount)
    {
        return byteCount;
    } 

}
```

Comment: Метод принимает только `string name`, если передать "1251" - тоже самое. На устройстве такая же ошибка, как и на эмуляторе. По поводу присутствия кодировки вопрос не понял. Ну я думаю что должна быть, в списке на msdn она есть https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Отредактировал ответ

Comment: тогда как быть с кодировкой `windows-1251`? Поддерживает её `Encoding` или нет, мне всё ещё необходимо её прочитать из массива байт. Или лучше создать отдельный вопрос для этого?

Comment: Обновил ответ... Сразу отмечу, код класса не мой. Я его где-то благополучно "позаимствовал" когда год назад столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой...

Comment: Пока что просто скопировал себе в проект, написал такой код:
`Encoding encoding = new Windows1251();
                    stringContent = encoding.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`

ошибка выхода за границу массива, сейчас буду искать где и почему

Comment: У меня вызывается так: 
Encoding encoding = new Windows1251(); Stream fs = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();byte[] bt = new byte[fs.Length]; fs.Read(bt, 0, (int)fs.Length); CurBookFileName = file.Name;
text = encoding.GetString(bt, 0, (int)fs.Length);
Может вам это поможет....

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33408/discussion-between-sudalv-and-alexey).